# "I had an assignment to complete for yesterday"

Tags: tense, verbs

If I said: "I had an assignment to complete for yesterday" what tense am I using?  (Esp 'for yesterday' bit)

Comment: You either had an assignment to complete yesterday or by yesterday - NOT for yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

> If I said: "I **had** an assignment **to complete** for yesterday" what tense am I using?

You are using the **past** tense.

### Had

There is only one finite verb in your sentence and it is a past tense form.  There is also no perfect or progressive construction, so this form ("had" on its own) is commonly referred to as "*simple past*" or "*past simple*".

**Tense** is a grammatical term referring to the inflection of a verb.  "I have" is present tense, "I had" is past tense.

**Tense** is *not* the same thing as *time*.  You can use the present tense to talk about future time ("I *leave* tomorrow", "I *am* free next Wednesday") and you can use the past tense to talk about a potential or hypothetical future ("If I *had* enough money, I would buy a yacht").

### Complete

"To complete" is an infinitive and has no tense.  Infinitives are non-finite, which means they are untensed.

The "for yesterday" bit doesn't contain any verbs and so is irrelevant to the question of tense.